# Node JS/Express: How to parse multipart response of external API Call

Tags: node.js, http, express, request, multipart

I made an external API call using npm [Request](https://github.com/request/request) module which returns a multipart form-data.

Here is the code snippet of the request (incomplete):

```
request.get(options, function (err, httpResponse, body) {
    if (err) {
        return console.error('Error:', err);
    }
    console.log(body);
});
```

Here is a sample of the response body (Console logged above):

```
--multipartBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="loremipsum.sample"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

TG9yZW0gSXBzdW0gaXMgc2ltcGx5IGR1bW15IHRleHQgb2YgdGhlIHByaW50aW5nIGFuZCB0eXBlc2V0dGluZyBpbmR1c3RyeS4gTG9yZW0gSXBzdW0gaGFzIGJlZW4gdGhlIGluZHVzdHJ5J3Mgc3RhbmRhcmQgZHVtbXkgdGV4dCBldmVyIHNpbmNlIHRoZSAxNTAwcywgd2hlbiBhbiB1bmtub3duIHByaW50ZXIgdG9vayBhIGdhbGxleSBvZiB0eXBlIGFuZCBzY3JhbWJsZWQgaXQgdG8gbWFrZSBhIHR5cGUgc3BlY2ltZW4gYm9vay4gSXQgaGFzIHN1cnZpdmVkIG5vdCBvbmx5IGZpdmUgY2VudHVyaWVzLCBidXQgYWxzbyB0aGUgbGVhcCBpbnRvIGVsZWN0cm9uaWMgdHlwZXNldHRpbmcsIHJlbWFpbmluZyBlc3NlbnRpYWxseSB1bmNoYW5nZWQuIEl0IHc=

--multipartBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json_detail"
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8

{
    "filename":"1478162481102.sdoc",
    "date_modified":"1478170365000",
}
--multipartBoundary--
```

**My questions are:**

1. Is it correct that this response is MultipartForm Data represented in stream/text?
2. How can I parse the response in a way that it returns file objects (two files in this case)?

**I believe that I cannot use middleware since this is an external API Call.
I tried the following:**

- Pipe to file (This just piped the response into a file)
- Http.get and busboy

*My last option seems to be to parse the response using Regex and write to file. This seems to be slow though*

Any input would be appreciated! Thank you!